# Circuitikz not drawing anything

Tags: circuitikz

I'm just learning `circuitikz` and I'm trying to draw just simple elements, such as :

```
\draw (0,0) to [V=$V$] (0,2);
```

And all I'm getting is the label (V) displayed, and not a voltage source.

I thought I might be doing something wrong, so I took some simple `circuitikz` code (from the `circuitikz` manual), and pasted it straight into my document (required some reformatting) and still got nothing.
I'm defining `circuitikz` in my preamble and I'm not getting any errors.
It may be a newb error, or even an installation problem (just installed tex live 2015), but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please give us a compilable code. We can not guess how you are entering that snippet you gave us to your main document.

Comment: This should work for you : `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
      \draw (0,0) to [V=$V$] (0,2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}`. If not give a MWE.

Comment: Nope - Just a math mode capital v in the middle of the page

Comment: @HarishKumar may not have seen that comment, as you didn't use a `@`-ping as I did here (in general only owners of posts are notified of comments). This is a long time ago, did you figure it out? If not, do you generate the PDF directly, or are you looking at a DVI?

Answer (score 2):

I took your code snippet and created a MWE, which works perfectly fine for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
            (0,0) to [V=$V$] (0,2)
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Try updating your packages by going to the MiKTeX Update (Admin). (Just press the windows key and search for "update", it'll pop up.)

Comment: About the updating, he's using TeX Live, not MikTeX. But anyway, [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) is probably a useful reference with regard to updating.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Oh, oops, my bad. I missed that little fact there.